# Facebook comment and like doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, facebook-like, facebook-comments

When using Chrome, FB comments and likes on websites doesn't go through. I've tried it being logged on to FB and being logged out as well. When logged in, a message pops up after a few seconds saying 'You are not logged in. Please log in and try again.'. When logged out, the login window pops up, I can login to FB, the comment box on the website shows my profile picture but when I try to send a comment, the same message pops up again. I've already deleted the cache and cookies, restared Chrome but nothing helpded. By the way, everything works fine in Firefox and IE.

I'd really appreciate some help on this issue.

Comment: this should be some issue with chrome

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions about programming, not about the problems you have using programs or websites. Ask Chrome and/or Facebook support if they know about this issue.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like there is a program (extension, toolbar...etc)  preventing your Facebook to login. Try to remove some (not all) extensions from Tools->Extensions if you think they are not known. Also, I suggest you to see Chrome Task Manager ( Tools ->Task Manager) if you see any suspicious program running try to stop it by clicking on ( End Process).

[image]

I hope that will solve your problem.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Do you happen to have any extension that might block access to social web pages? Otherwise, I think there is no valid explanation for this. Regards.

P.S. Try reinstalling Chrome without signing into your gmail account (if you have one) and sync everything.